# How to tap on Modal's Continue button without testIds in Detox E2E Testing for React Native app with Auth0 Universal Login?

Tags: react-native, detox

In my React Native application, I am using Detox for end-to-end testing. My app's authorization flow includes Auth0 Universal Login, and I am struggling to find a way to tap on the "Continue" button within the Modal since there are no test IDs associated with either the Modal or the button. Can anyone suggest a solution or workaround for this issue? [image]

I have tried the following code to access the modal but It's not working

```
waitFor(element(by.traits(['modal']))).toBeVisible();
const continueButton = element(by.text('Continue'));
await expect(continueButton).toBeVisible();
await continueButton.tap();
```